# Restricting templated class datatypes

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class definitions:

```
// A TileBase contains a deceleration for game events that will be present in 
// Static and Dynamic tiles
class TileBase

// To use tiles in your game, create a tile base for Tile to inherit from, then 
// create game-specific tiles as derivitives of StaticTile or DynamicTile
template<typename aTileBase> class Tile : public aTileBase
```

Classes `StaticTile` and `DynamicTile` are derived from `Tile`. The goal is to have methods declared in a `TileBase` present in all derived classes of `Tile` via a dynamic cast.

I would like to restrict `Tile`'s template definition to only accept datatypes derived from `TileBase`. Is there any way to accomplish this without using a dynamic cast and assertion at runtime?

Comment: Using a `dynamic_cast` is an indicator of a flawed design.  Unnecessarily limiting template types is also frowned upon.  Are you familiar with [duck typing](/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Ah! Thank you for pointing this out. I realize now that I was going to create extraneous logic. This implementation works without the need for dynamic_cast. Also, in this case would restricting template types be considered bad form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy to do using [`std::is_base_of<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

```
template<typename aTileBase> 
class Tile : public aTileBase {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<TileBase, aTileBase>::value, "");

  [...]
};
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here... will a static assert trigger at compile time?

Comment: @NoahRoseLedesma, yes, that's what makes it static :)

Comment: This works wonderfully. I am surprised however that there is no syntax along the lines of `template<typename T : Base >`

Comment: @NoahRoseLedesma - Just be sure to write a descriptive error message as the second argument to static_assert. Otherwise people will only get to see the "how" of your check, and they probably need the "why" as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've written "Template type for Tile must be of type TileBase". Is there a way to print a stack trace of this assertion? That would make it much easier to debug